# Splitting cells content in row range add sum it up - Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one row like the one in the picture below and I'd like to sum up the numerator in the range `A1:D1`, so: `4+4+3+4`. I tried replicating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536302/how-to-split-and-sum-in-google-sheets) but I couldn't make it work. Basically I need to recompute the averages that you see individually in each cell, ending up with `15/35`. Is there a way to do it with a single formula?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,tocol(A1:D1,1),sum(index(split(Σ,"/"),,1))&"/"&sum(index(split(Σ,"/ "),,2)))
```

***OR***

```js
=let(Σ,index(split(tocol(A1:D1,1),"/ ")),sum(index(Σ,,1))&"/"&sum(index(Σ,,2)))
```

[image]